# Processing sketch does not work in Browser

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

I created a sketch in Processing and I would like to put it on a website using Processing.js. I created an html page to put the sketch in and tested it out, but all I see is white screen. The sketch doesn't work.

I've read through the Processing.js Quick Start and as far as I can tell, I've resolved any problems with my sketch and processing.js. My next thought was that there was something wrong with the way I wrote the HTML page, or maybe my browser, but when I tested it with a simpler sketch, that sketch worked just fine. So there has to be something wrong with the sketch itself, but I can't figure out what it is.

For reference, here is the link to where the sketch is supposed to be and the source code of my sketch.

[Site](http://krotalov.net/NonJoomla/welcome2.html)
[Code](http://krotalov.net/NonJoomla/WarefareBeta1_3.txt)

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Edit: Here's the error recieved in the console:uncaught exception: Processing.js: Unable to load pjs sketch files: WarefareBeta1_3/WarefareBeta1_3.pde ==> Invalid XHR status 404

Comment: Its giving a 404 message. Can't find the sketch, is my guess. Also next time, add the warning messages that you see in the console of your browser to your question. **It doesn't work** is way too vague.

Comment: My apologies, I'm not really familiar with web development at all, I wasn't aware regular browsers had a console until just now. But why would it not be able to find the file? I mentioned I tested a simpler sketch and it was able to find that one. I referenced it in the same way, the only difference is the complexity of the sketch.

Comment: I couldn't tell you. Its Processing.js. It is a pain in the butt. I avoid Processing.js like the plague, sticking with regular Processing, because it is almost impossible to know what the heck is going wrong. I could do some tests on it in a couple of days when I have the time and if you haven't received a reply still.

Comment: case matters, and the files are resolved relative to your index.html, so in the same dir you have index.html, let's call that dir `X`, there'd need to be an `X/WarefareBeta1_3/WarefareBeta1_3.pde`, with that exact same case.

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute URL in your data-processing-sources (something like `http://krotalov.net/NonJoomla/WarefareBeta1_3/WarefareBeta1_3.pde`).

Because the file you mention
there now, `WarefareBeta1_3/WarefareBeta1_3.pde` does not seem to be on the server. Or at least not in that directory.